# Automatically submit a tinymce form after a certain count of words written in the textarea field

Tags: javascript, forms, textarea, form-submit

Is it possible to automatically submit a tinymce form after a certain name of words written in the textarea field? I tried this but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <form method="post" id="form" action="getform.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-4">
                <label>Content</label>
                <textarea name="dopamine" id="tinymce"></textarea>
            </div>
            
            <button class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
    $('#tinymce').keyup(function(){
        if(this.value.length ==10){
        $('#Form').submit();
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your form does not have the Id `#Form`. Set this value as id for your form then try again

Comment: Yes excuse me I had already tried (I just added the form ID).